# Как получить данные из массива js?

Tags: javascript

есть переменная, при выводе ее в консоль

```
console.log(filters);
```

, отражается следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как получить только данные из этого массива? `field_price_auto`

попробовал вот так: `console.log(filters.field_price_auto);`, но `undefined`, что не так, может быть к нему нужно как то по другому обращаться?

может быть можно преобразовать в какой то другой тип данных чтобы можно было по дереву искать?

Comment: Есть смутное подозрение, что ты данные получаешь `ajax-ом`, скорее всего на момент запроса `console.log(filters.field_price_auto);` данные еще не подгрузились... попробуй через `setInterval()`

Comment: если так то странно, что когда я вывожу в консоль filters, то в массиве эти данные есть, а если есть, то по идее я к ним могу обратиться, иначе бы массив был пуст

Comment: спорить не буду, но setInterval помог, хотя думал что переменная уже сформирована плностью

Comment: У меня не было срочной потребности, более подробно ковыряться... Но у меня было так же с `DOM-элементами`, которые подгружались  `ajax-ом`, так что прости, помочь конкретно не могу, как в данной ситуации надо грамотно поступить...

Answer (score 0):

У вас написано, что это объект. Предположу, что если название `filters`, то будет

`console.log(filters['field_price_auto']['id']);`

для примера

Comment: пробовал
даже просто вот так console.log(filters['field_price_auto']); но все равно undefined

Comment: а если filters->field_price_auto

Comment: или еще вот попробуйте filters[0] я не знаю откуда строится у вас переменная, поэтому могу только гадать))

Comment: насколько я знаю это уже не js, попробовал

Comment: тогда вставьте в сообщение, что генерирует эту переменную, а то мало информации очень